# react-three. When using a loop, the models are not displayed

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I have a list of objects that describe the models that should be rendered. If you try to run them through the loop, they are not displayed.

```
function Model({model, position}) {
    const result = useLoader(GLTFLoader, './models/car/top/topFront.glb')
    return <primitive 
        object={result.scene} 
        position={[1,1,1]}
        onPointerOver={()=>changeToSelect(result)}
        onPointerOut={()=>chageToUnselect(result)}
        material={
          new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({ color: 'black', flatShading: true })
        }
    />
  }
```

```
{cars.forEach(car=>{
          <Model
          model={car['path']}
          position={car['position']}
         />
        })}
```

Here is object: {name:'Middle top part', path:'./models/car/top/topMiddle.glb', position:'1,3,1'}

It also doesn't work when trying to output standard elements:

```
{cars.forEach(()=>{
            <mesh>
              <boxGeometry />
              <meshStandardMaterial />
            </mesh>
         })}
```

Comment: I have not db for all values. They contains in json file with objects, like the one I specified.

Comment: I solve this.
map just needed a "return".
Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

**I converted a forEach to map**

```
{cars.map((car, index)=>(
       <Model
       key={index}
       model={car['path']}
       position={car['position']}
      />
))}
```